# Possible number of matrices with given $4$ different elements

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, combinations

I want to know the possible number of matrices that are $10\times10$ and are going to be filled with $4$ different numbers. So, every element of the matrix has $4$ possibilities to take. Does $4^{10\times10}$ does the job?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: To visualise this, unroll the matrix into a collection of $10\times10 = 100$ boxes. Each of these boxes can be filled in exactly four ways. Hence, there are $4^{100}$ ways in which the task can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I know that it was a very easy question for the StackExchange (maybe even improper) but I needed an immediate answer to try something in a program that deals with a large number of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have done this problem correctly.

Comment: Answering in Community Wiki so this question can be marked answered.